# Two fixed div in same line, one in left, one in right

Tags: css

Is it possible to have two fixed div in same line, one in left, one in right, inside a container, aligned to the margins of that container?

Any solution must be ie8 compatible and center div must be responsive with 50% width.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.left {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
}
.right {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: blue;
}
.center {
  display: inline-table;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="center">center</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not use purecss?

Comment: What pure css? A demo please?

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
.right {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 50px;
  position: static;
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Position static is not ok because the right div will scroll with the rest of the page. Position fixed keeps it in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

Try It

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tp6txmjw/)

### CSS

```
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  width:100%;
  display: table;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.left {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.right {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
}
.center {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 35%;
}
```

Comment: Close but center has issue in responsive mode. Please see https://jsfiddle.net/Adyyda/tp6txmjw/1/ - change the width of the demo section to simulate responsive. So your solution is ok if we use a fixed width container.

Comment: Olso i do not see in your demo any fixed positions which are required?

Comment: Why you need ?  not required .

Comment: because header that contains the elements changes from relative to a fixed one